# how to do i fire this code on click of a button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, timer, click, countdowntimer

i'm new to JavaScript and i want this code to start with a click of a button and also in every click it should start a new different timer from zero. anyone here to help!

```js
// add a count-down timer
 function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function () {
      minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
      seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

      display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

      if (--timer < 0) {
          timer = duration;
      }
  }, 1000);
}
var butt = window.document.getElementById('button');
window.onload = function () { //i tried using ' butt.onclick' but this did not work
  var fiftenMinutes = 60 * 15,
      display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(fiftenMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<h3 id="time" class="divTime"></h3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add a button with an id of "button" to make your code work:

```
<button id="button">Button Text</button>
```

Next, each time you click the button, you want the previous interval to be cancelled, otherwise you'll end up with more and more intervals changing the content of the `h3`:

```
var intervalId

...

if (intervalId) clearInterval(intervalId)

intervalId = setInterval(function() {})
```

This leaves us with the following:

```js
var intervalId;

// add a count-down timer
 function startTimer(duration, display) {
 if (intervalId) clearInterval(intervalId);
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
  intervalId = setInterval(function () {
      minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
      seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

      display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

      if (--timer < 0) {
          timer = duration;
      }
  }, 1000);
}
var butt = window.document.getElementById('button');
butt.onclick = function () { //i tried using ' butt.onclick' but this did not work
  var fiftenMinutes = 60 * 15,
      display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(fiftenMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<h3 id="time" class="divTime"></h3>
<button id="button">Button Text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a different timer each time you click, you need to add an element dynamically to the DOM to hold it.

```js
// add a count-down timer
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
window.onload = function() { //i tried using ' butt.onclick' but this did not work
  var fiftenMinutes = 60 * 15,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(fiftenMinutes, display);
};
var butt = window.document.getElementById('button');
butt.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var new_h3 = document.createElement("h3");
  document.body.appendChild(new_h3);
  startTimer(60*15, new_h3);
})
```

```html
<h3 id="time" class="divTime"></h3>
<button id="button">Start timer</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it really helped. this is what i was looking for, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add event listener to the button and clear already set timer, if it has been set. Run the following snippet.

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
        var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
        
        return setInterval(function () {
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
      
            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
      
            display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds + ' Click to Restart';
      
            if (--timer < 0) {
                timer = duration;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
    
    var timerID = null;
    
    // replace 'time' if the h3 element isn't the button.
    document.getElementById( 'time' ).addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        if ( timerID ) {
            clearInterval( timerID );
        }
    
        var fiftenMinutes = 60 * 15,
            display = document.querySelector('#time');
    
        timerID = startTimer(fiftenMinutes, display);
    })
```

```html
<h3 id="time" class="divTime">Click To Start Timer</h3>
```